# Range of values based on key values

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, 2d

I'm trying to implement a method of searching through a large amount of 2D points for those that match a certain range. I'm thinking of creating HashMaps for `<X, Point>` and `<Y, Point>` but I'm wondering is HashMap good for doing this, because I will be taking points in a range, based on values from x_min to x_max and y_min to y_max.

So I will basically take all points from `<X,Point>` searching from x_min to x_max and compare them to points taken from `<Y,Point>` from y_min to y_max...

```
HashMap<Integer,Point> x_coordinates = new HashMap<Integer,Point>();
for(int i=x_min;i<=x_max;i++){
    if(x_coordinates.containsKey(i))
        x_coordinates.get(i);
}

HashMap<Integer,Point> y_coordinates = new HashMap<Integer,Point>();
for(int i=y_min;i<=y_max;i++){
    if(y_coordinates.containsKey(i))
         y_coordinates.get(i);
}
```

Is there a faster way to get a range of values from a HashMap, or some other type of data structure?

Comment: When you say "match a given range", do you mean "fall inside a specified rectangle"? Or "are at most a certain distance from a point"? Or something else?

Comment: I mean `"fall inside a specified rectangle"` which is an optimisation of `"are at most a certain distance from a point"` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found a solution with:

```
TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Integer>> values;
for (int x : values.subMap(x_min, x_max).keySet()) {
        for (int y : values.get(x).subMap(y_min, y_max).values()) {
            // y here, represents the value of points in range...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is better since it supports many features like floor, higher,lower, ceiling, etc.
 Thanks to it you can create a single map `TreeMap<Integer,Point> coordinates = new TreeMap<Integer,Point>();` and then query it for coordinates of your interest. Note that TreeMap is sorted according to the `natural ordering` of its keys, or by a `Comparator` provided at map creation time.

If you are looking for some more sophisticated search queries, then have a look at [quad-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)

Comment: but what would `Integer` represent in `TreeMap<Integer,Point>` ?